# How to transpose a single column into an index row in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, transpose

This is my dataset:

| Name | Assignment | Scores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Boo | Test1 | 0.9 |
| Buzz | Test3 | 0.7 |
| Bree | Test2 | 1.0 |
| Boo | Quiz | 1.0 |
| Buzz | Test1 | 0.8 |

How I want my result:

| Name | Test1 | Test3 | Test2 | Quiz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boo | 0.9 | 0 | 0 | 1.0 |
| Buzz | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0 | 0 |
| Bree | 0 | 0 | 1.0 | 0 |

.T only seems to work for the entire df and I tried .pivot() as well :/
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pivot_table`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

```
df.pivot_table('Scores', index='Name', columns='Assignment', fill_value=0)
```